# ActiveRecord presence validation for has_many through assosiation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am having an issue with Rails validations that I will try to explain here.

Imagine I have this scenario:

Parent has many ParentChild,
Child has many ParentChild,
ParentChild belongs to both Parent and Child,
Also, Parents can be active or inactive.

I need to validate the presence of Child on active Parents. To do so I wrote this code:

```
validates :child, presence: { message: "can't be blank on active parents" }, if: -> (parent) { parent.active? }
```

And it kind of works.

Let's say I have this Parent with 4 children associated to it and I remove those 4 associated children from it. The validation then fires up and adds the error message to the Parent Model, but it won't prevent the removal of the associated children.

Basically, the associated children is being removed AND the validation occurs.

I also tried with a custom validation or even a before_validation callback to manually check the removal of the children but nothing seems to work.

Any help here would be kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about you add `before_destroy` callback inside `ParentChild` model

```
...
  before_destroy :check_if_last
...

private

def check_if_last
  if parent.active? && parent.children.count == 1
    errors.add(:child, "can't be blank on active parents")       
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, I also tried this and not only it is not working at all but even if it worked the behavior would be a little weird.

Imagine you delete all four children at once, the validation would leave one "random" and the user would be shown an error.

I would prefer to rollback the whole deletion in the case of failing the validation.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to destroy relationship, you can hook on the relationship model itself. Just take note of the return false. In order to rollback the transaction by a callback you need to return a false, yes a false not a falsy value, otherwise it will still commit.

```
  before_destroy :last_of_active_parent?

  private

  def last_of_active_parent?
    if parent.active? && parent.children.count == 1
      errors.add(:parent, "which is active can't lose the last child") 
      false      
    end
  end
```

Comment: Nope, I am destroying the relation, not the Child itself. So before_destroy on Child won't get called in this case.